# Comparing two maps key with possibility of None and null in scala

Tags: scala

I have this two `Map[String, String]` and I need to create new map with updated value. Update is done if second Map have new key or non-null value or value greater than of first Map.

For example:

**Updating Scenario**

- if `FirstMap("key1" -> "123")` and `SecondMap("key1" -> "456")` then `ResultMap("key1" -> "456")`
- if `FirstMap("key1" -> null)` and `SecondMap("key1" -> "value1")` then `ResultMap("key1" -> "value1")`
- if `FirstMap()` and `SecondMap("key1" -> "value1")` then `ResultMap("key1" -> "value1")`

**Non-Updating Scenario**

- if `FirstMap("key1" -> "value1")` and `SecondMap()` then
  `ResultMap("key1" -> "value1")`
- if `FirstMap("key1" -> "value1")` and `SecondMap("key1" -> null)` then `ResultMap("key1" -> "value1")`
- if `FirstMap("key1" -> "789")` and `SecondMap("key1" -> "456")` then `ResultMap("key1" -> "789")`

So far I have code below:

```
val currentFieldValue = currentDetail.get(field).get
val newFieldValue = newDetail.get(field).get

currentFieldValue match {
  case null if newFieldValue != null => currentDetail ++ Map(s"$field" -> s"$newFieldValue")
  case _ if newFieldValue != null && newFieldValue.toInt > currentFieldValue.toInt => currentDetail ++ Map(s"$field" -> s"$newFieldValue")
  case _  => currentDetail
}
```

Any suggestion on how to accommodate `None` state i.e. when key itself itsn't there?

Comment: `case None` doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map.get(key)` returns `Option` pattern match on the option and create as many relevant cases as you want

```
(currentDetail.get(field), newDetail.get(field)) match {
  case (Some(null), Some(null)) =>
  case (Some(null), Some(value)) =>
  case (Some(value), Some(null)) => 
  case (Some(value), None) =>
  case (None, Some(value)) =>
  case (None, None) =>
  case (_, _) =>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just as alternative here is complete compare function (with debug msgs):

```
def compare(currentDetail: Map[String, String], newDetail: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
  var resMap = Map[String, String]()
  currentDetail.keys.foreach { field =>

    val currentField = currentDetail.get(field)
    val newField = newDetail.get(field)

    resMap = resMap + {
      (currentField, newField) match {
        case (Some(null), Some(newFieldValue: String)) =>
          println("null and not null")
          (s"${field}" -> newFieldValue)
        case (Some(currentFieldValue), Some(null)) =>
          println("not null and null")
          (s"${field}" -> currentFieldValue)
        case (None, Some(newFieldValue)) =>
          println("none and not null")
          (s"${field}" -> newFieldValue)
        case (Some(currentFieldValue), None) =>
          println("not null and none")
          (s"${field}" -> currentFieldValue)
        case (Some(currentFieldValue), Some(newFieldValue)) if newFieldValue.toInt > currentFieldValue.toInt =>
          println("not null not null if new bigger then current")
          (s"${field}" -> newFieldValue)
        case (Some(currentFieldValue), Some(newFieldValue)) if newFieldValue.toInt <= currentFieldValue.toInt =>
          println("not null not null if new less or equal to current")
          (s"${field}" -> currentFieldValue)
      }
    }
  }

  resMap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def combine(m1: Map[String,String], m2: Map[String,String]): Map[String,String] =
  (m1.keys ++ m2.keys).toSet.map{ k: String =>
    k -> Seq(Option(m1.getOrElse(k,"")), Option(m2.getOrElse(k,"")), Some(""))
         .flatten.sorted.reverse.head
  }.toMap
```

`"456" > "123"` is true for both `String` and `Int`.  What if you have two strings `"99"` and `"101"`?  If you need number comparisons then that's going to require lots more code to transit between `String`->`Int`->`String`.